# Spinejs: binding events for nested controllers

Tags: spine.js, event-binding

I'm having a problem with nested controller like this

For example, I have controller A

```
class A extends Spine.Controller
  events:
   'click .foo' : 'handle_bar'
```

Then I create two instance of A like this

```
a = new A
b = new A
a.append b
```

When I click on .foo inside b, then b.handle_bar is called. But a.handle_bar is called as well.

How to prevent that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you end up nesting `b` inside of `a` with `a.append b` events that happen in `b` are also happening in `a`. It would probably be a bad idea for Spine controllers in general to stop propagation of events to prevent this, but you could implement that solution on `b` if you needed to.